# Nuclear reaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

If boron reacts with a thermal neutron and produces an excited lithium and a ground state helium, what will be the function of this reaction in a nuclear reactor?

Will the potential energy of the products be increased and kinetic energy be decreased?

Comment: Well, what does the reaction look like?

Comment: I am sorry as I donot know how to write a reaction over here...but i hope you will understand the following reaction-
Boron(10)+Neutron(1)= Lithium (asterisk)(7)+ Helium(4).

Here, asterisk means lithium is excited above its ground state.

Comment: As you mentioned in your previous question about the nuclear binding energy curve, fission of light elements absorbs energy (it's an endothermic reaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a thermal neutron nuclear reactor, the primary function of boron is to absorb thermal neutrons to decrease the number of fissions on 235U. Boron acts as a control rod and it doesn't matter how much energy is released by this reaction which is small compared to the loss of a fission. By losing a fission, you lose about 200 MeV, while the reaction on boron produces only 2.31 MeV. The boron can be present in the control rods, or it is injected directly into the light water of the primary circuit in the form of boric acid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean, no matter what kind (excited or normal kind) of products it(boron) produces and how much energy it will release, it will absorb neutron as usual?

Comment: At each capture of a neutron by a boron atom, this boron atom disappears (by the reaction that you have quoted).
Thus, boron is consumed and you must renew the quantity of boric acid injected in the primary water if you want to continue to benefit from its neutron absorbing effect on the whole volume of the core. Otherwise, of course, the effective capture cross section of boron remains constant for thermal neutrons with a value of about 3800 barns.

Comment: Thanks. So, it will cost more money. However, why this reaction (producing excited lithium and ground state helium) happens in the core?

Comment: The injection of boric acid in the primary water allows a uniform control of the power of the reactor on the whole volume of the core and avoids movements of control rods, which saves the mechanisms of control rods which are very expensive: the economic balance is positive.
The neutron absorptions are done on the whole volume of the core, because the thermal neutrons are present on the whole volume of the core, as well as the fissions, which occur in the fuel on the whole volume of the core. And primary water crosses core permanently .

Comment: I am really sorry for my english. We know, usually boron produce helium(ground state) and lithium(ground state) by releasing 2.8Mev energy in a core. But, instead of producing a ground state lithium, why this reaction produce an excited lithium?

Comment: After the capture of a thermal neutron by 10B, there are 2 ways of disintegration:
- Obtaining 7Li ground state at 6% probability ,
- Obtaining 7Li excited state at 94%probability.
I note that it is like this.
I do not know why, it is a difficult question of fundamental nuclear physics.
As the lifetime of the excited state is about 100 fs, this has no importance in reactor physics.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The function of boron in  reactor is a *poison*, as it exhibits a strong tendency to capture neutrons and thereby reduce the reactivity of the core.

By adding boron-containing chemicals to the cooling water in a reactor core, the overall reactivity of the core can be fine-tuned by the reactor operators.

Comment: Will there be any effect on its neutron capturing function if it (boron) produces an excited lithium after reacting with a thermal neutron?

Comment: I do not know, but wikipedia knows. -NN

Comment: Once the boron absorption occurs, the lithium will have a cross section, but it is negligible compared to boron.  Also note that the "excited" lithium is very short lived, it can just be referred to as lithium 7.